# Slow While loop in C#

Tags: c#, performance, loops, while-loop

I have a `while` loop and all it does is a method call. I have a timer on the outside of the loop and another timer that incrementally adds up the time the method call takes inside the loop. The outer time takes about 17 seconds and the total on the inner timer is 40 ms. The loop is executing 50,000 times. Here is an example of the code:

```
long InnerTime = 0;
long OutterTime = 0;
Stopw1.Start();
int count = 1;
while (count <= TestCollection.Count) {
    Stopw2.Start();
    Medthod1();
    Stopw2.Stop();
    InnerTime = InnerTime + Stopw2.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Stopw2.Reset();
    count++;
}
Stopw1.Stop();
OutterTime = Stopw1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Stopw1.Reset();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Massimo

Comment: Have you tried removing the inner loop timing code and seeing if it speeds up?

Comment: Code seems to be just fine, except the "Method1", which we dont know what it does. Else, concerning timer seems all ok!

Comment: What is `TestCollection` - is it a method, a variable/property or what? Try replacing `TestCollection.Count` with a constant (obviously one low enough not to fall over).

Comment: Try doing `int countLimit = TestCollection.Count` outside the loop and using countLimit in your condition. It may be a pretty expensive evaluation if the collection is highly dynamic.

Comment: If TestCollection is an instance of Collection<T> or List<T>, Count is a O(1) operation. Unless it's some kind of inefficient custom class, it shouldn't be causing the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges. Your outer timer measures the total time taken. Your inner timer measures the number of *whole* milliseconds taken by the call to `Method1`.

The [ElapsedMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds.aspx)  property "represents elapsed time rounded down to the nearest whole millisecond value." So, you are rounding **down** to the nearest millisecond about 50,000 times.

If your call to `Method1` takes, on average, less than 1ms, then most of the time, the `ElapsedMilliseconds' property will return 0 and your inner count will be much, much less than the actual time. In fact, your method takes about 0.3ms on average, so you're lucky even to get it to go over 1ms 40 times.

Use the `Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` or `ElapsedTicks` property instead of `ElapsedMilliseconds`. One millisecond is equivalent to 10,000 ticks.

Comment: Using the ElapsedTicks showed a much more accurate reflection of the time.There turned out to only be a 72 ms time difference.Thank you Jeffrey

Answer (score 2):

What is this doing: `TestCollection.Count` ?

I suspect your 17 seconds are being spent counting your 50,000 items over and over again.

Comment: You think it is counting faculty of 50,000 times? Would be interesting what's the type of `TestCollection`.

Comment: You are probably thinking of the Linq `Count()` expression and not the `ICollection.Count` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
while (count <= TestCollection.Count) {
...
}
```

to this:

```
int total = TestCollection.Count;
while (count <= total) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to what the others have already said, in general the C# compiler must re-evaluate any property, including

```
TestCollection.Count
```

for every single loop iteration.  The property's value could change from iteration to iteration.

Assigning the value to a local variable removes the compiler's need to re-evaluate for every loop iteration.

The one exception that I'm aware of is for Array.Length, which benefits from an optimization specifically for arrays.  This is referred to as [Array Bounds Check Elimination](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/08/13/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr.aspx).

Comment: ICollection.Count usually just returns a private field value. Although the value could change and cause issues, I don't think 'reevaluating the property' is the problem.

Comment: Sure, I think the real issue is that he's not measuring properly as @Jeffrey pointed out.  Just added this for completeness.  Sometimes property evaluation *is* expensive relative to the loop body (just not here).

Answer (score 0):

To have a correct measurement of the time that your calls take,
you should use the Ticks

Please try the following:

```
long InnerTime = 0;
long OutterTime = 0;

Stopwatch Stopw1 = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch Stopw2 = new Stopwatch();

Stopw1.Start();
int count = 1;
int run = TestCollection.Count;
while (count <= run) {
    Stopw2.Start();
    Medthod1();
    Stopw2.Stop();
    InnerTime = InnerTime + Stopw2.ElapsedTicks;
    Stopw2.Reset();
    count++;
}
Stopw1.Stop();
OutterTime = Stopw1.ElapsedTicks;
Stopw1.Reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not measure such a tiny method individually. But if you really want to, try this:

```
long innertime = 0;

while (count <= TestCollection.Count) 
{     
    innertime -= Stopw2.GetTimestamp();
    Medthod1();
    innertime += Stopw2.GetTimestamp();
    count++; 
} 

Console.WriteLine("{0} ms", innertime * 1000.0 / Stopw2.Frequency);
```